# c# Find an item in 2 / multiple lists

Tags: c#, generics

I have the presumably common problem of having elements that I wish to place in 2 (or more) lists. However sometimes I want to find an element that could be in one of the lists. Now there is more than one way of doing this eg using linq or appending, but all seem to involve the unnecessary creation of an extra list containing all the elements of the separate lists and hence waste processing time.

So I was considering creating my own generic FindinLists class which would take 2 lists as its constructor parameters would provide a Find() and an Exists() methods. The Find and Exists methods would only need to search the second or subsequent lists if the item was not found in the first list. The FindInLists class could be instantiated in the getter of a ( no setter)property. A second constructor for the FindInLists class could take an array of lists as its parameter.

Is this useful or is there already a way to search multiple lists without incurring the wasteful overhead of the creation of a super list?

Comment: Do you want that one element can only be in one of the lists, or is it possible that the same element can be in one or more lists? What are the rules for placing elements in the lists in the first place? Why do you think you need to create a super list?

Comment: I was under the misapprehension that IEnumerable created a super list. It seems in effect just to create a wrapper around the lists or lists from which it is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `IEnumerable<T>.Concat()` is what you need. It doesn't create an extra list, it only iterates through the given pair of collections when queried

`Concat()` uses deferred execution, so at the time it's called it only creates an iterator which stores the reference to both concatenated IEnumerables. At the time the resulting collection is enumerated, it iterates through first and then through the second.
Here's the decompiled code for the iterator - no rocket science going on there:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    foreach (TSource iteratorVariable0 in first)
    {
        yield return iteratorVariable0;
    }
    foreach (TSource iteratorVariable1 in second)
    {
        yield return iteratorVariable1;
    }
}
```

When looking to the docs for Concat(), I've stumbled across another alternative I didn't know - `SelectMany`. Given a collection of collections it allows you to work with the children of all parent collections at once like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> concatenated = new[] { firstColl, secondColl }
    .SelectMany(item => item);
```

Comment: Is this definite? I guess IEnumerable just provides a wrapper for the underlying collection or collections.

Comment: The concat gives you an iterator which of course needs to carry reference to the source collections. But no new collection with all the items is created. I've added more detail to the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Linq already has this functionality by virtue of the [FirstOrDefault method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). It uses deferred execution so will stream from any input and will short circuit the return when a matching element is found.

```
var matched = list1.Concat(list2).FirstOrDefault(e => element.Equals(e));
```

Update

```
BaseType matched = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).FirstOrDefault(e => element.Equals(e));
```

Comment: Just for clarity could you give us the syntax.

Comment: Ah cheers, can I put BaseType instead of var where lists are of dervived from basetype. Also for three lists: Var matched =list1.Union(list2).Union(list3).FirstOrDefault(e => element.Equals(e)); //works?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the LINQ Concat function.

```
var query = list1.Concat(list2).Where(x => x.Category=="my category");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
var list1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
var list2 = new List<int>{0,-3,-4,2};

int elementToPush = 4;//value to find among available lists

var exist = list1.Exists(i=>i==elementToPush) || list2.Exists(j=>j==elementToPush);
```

If **at least** one collection required element exists, result is `false`, otherwise it's `true`.

**One row and no external storage creation.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will that not execute `list2.Exists(j=>j==elementToPush)` far more than it needs to? And why have that part inside the list1.Exists and not just do: `list1.Exists(i=>i==elementToPush) || list2.Exists(j=>j==elementToPush);`?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just create a List of lists and then use linq on that list. It is still creating a new List but it is a list of references rather than duplicating the contents of all the lists.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>{"apple", "aardvark"};
List<string> b = new List<string>{"banana", "bananananana", "bat"};
List<string> c = new List<string>{"cat", "canary"};
List<string> d = new List<string>{"dog", "decision"};

List<List<string>> super = new List<List<string>> {a,b,c,d};

super.Any(x=>x.Contains("apple"));
```

the Any call should return after the first list returns true so as requested will not process later lists if it finds it in an earlier list.

**Edit:** Having written this I prefer the answers using `Concat` but I leave this here as an alternative if you want something that might be more aesthetically pleasing. ;-)